# Problem with a updating a post on Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8; I can create posts, but I cannot update the posts. Below is my update function. Please feel free to point out if there are any errors in my code.

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);
    
    // Update Post
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->update($request->all());
    $post->save();
    
    return redirect('/posts');
}
```

My edit page is:

```
@extends('layouts.apps')
@section('content')
<h1 class="font-bold text-3xl text-red-700 text-center"><strong>Edit this Post</strong> </h1>

@if (Auth::check()) 
@include('includes.messages')

    <form action= "posts/{post} " method="POST" class="mx-60 bg-red-300 border-2 border-black">
        @method('PUT')
        @csrf
        <div class="py-5">
            <label for="Title">Title</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
        </div>
        <div class="py-5">
            <label for="body">Description</label>
            <br>
            <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="50" rows="3" class="self-stretch"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="py-5">
            <label for="evidencePhoto">Attach photo</label>
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="evidencePhoto" id="evidencePhoto">
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
            <input type="reset" class="bg-gray-200 px-2 mx-4 text-center hover:border-white border-4 border-black md:rounded-lg">
            <button type="submit" class="px-4 w-24  hover:border-green-800 border-4 border-black bg-green-400 text-yellow md:rounded-lg"><strong>Post</strong></button>
            <a href="/posts" class="mx-4 px-2"><div class="bg-gray-200 text-center hover:border-red-700 border-4 border-black"><strong>>>Back to Posts<<</strong></div></a>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div class="">
        <h1 class="font-bold text-3xl text-red-700 text-center"><strong>Warning!</strong> </h1>
        <p class="text-red-700 text-center"><strong>Please avoid the use of this platform for the spread of fake news.</strong> 
        You will be held responsible for any fake hazard alert you post on this platform.
        </p>
    </div>   
        
        
            
        @else
            
                <div class="flex justify-center px-10 place-content-center bg-red-200 text-center border-6 border-black">
                   <p> You are not authorized to post on this platform</p>
                  <strong><a href="/register" class="border-red.600 text-blue bg-gray-200 hover:text-red-600 border-4">Create an account</a> OR <a href="/login" class="text-blue border-red.600 bg-gray-200 hover:text-red-600 border-4">Log in</a>to be eligible.</strong>
                </div>
                
        @endif      
      
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you are finding post using find() function
   so replace it with findOrFail()
2. firstly you are finding a post using id then you are using both functions update() and save() so it will be error.

replace it with

$post = Post::findOrFail($id);

$post->title = $request->input('title');

$post->body= $request->input('body');

$post->save();

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I have tried what you recommended but it is still not working.